# RAID1 setup not using full disk space

Tags: raid, disk, partitioning, ext4, dmraid

I have two solid state drives and two rotary drives. These are /dev/sd{a,b} and /dev/sd{c,d} respectively. The two solid state drivers contain my root installation in a fake RAID1 array. The latter two rotary drives are a fake RAID1 array containing my home directory.

The rotary drives are each 2.73 TB drives. However, assembled into a RAID1 array it shows up as only 746 GB. I would like this home drive's ext4 array to use the full capacity of the drives.

`$ sudo dmraid -r
ERROR: unsupported sector size 4096 on /dev/dm-6.
ERROR: unsupported sector size 4096 on /dev/sde.
/dev/sda: isw, "isw_cehacfhcg", GROUP, ok, 488397166 sectors, data@ 0
/dev/sdc: isw, "isw_eabehgedbj", GROUP, ok, 5860533166 sectors, data@ 0
/dev/sdb: isw, "isw_cehacfhcg", GROUP, ok, 488397166 sectors, data@ 0
/dev/sdd: isw, "isw_eabehgedbj", GROUP, ok, 5860533166 sectors, data@ 0`

`$ sudo dmraid -s
ERROR: unsupported sector size 4096 on /dev/dm-6.
ERROR: unsupported sector size 4096 on /dev/sde.
* Group superset isw_cehacfhcg
--> Active Subset
name   : isw_cehacfhcg_GNU_RAID1_PAIR
size   : 488390912
stride : 128
type   : mirror
status : ok
subsets: 0
devs   : 2
spares : 0
* Group superset isw_eabehgedbj
--> Active Subset
name   : isw_eabehgedbj_HOME_RAID1_PAIR
size   : 1565561088
stride : 128
type   : mirror
status : ok
subsets: 0
devs   : 2
spares : 0`

`$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/ram0: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes`

Disk /dev/ram1: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/ram2: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/ram3: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/ram4: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/ram5: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/ram6: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/ram7: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/ram8: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/ram9: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/ram10: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/ram11: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/ram12: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/ram13: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/ram14: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/ram15: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

GPT PMBR size mismatch (488390919 != 488397167) will be corrected by w(rite).
Disk /dev/sda: 232.9 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 079A0748-C6FE-4AF3-AA2B-0C7B0DAE147D

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sda2    1050624 421537791 420487168 200.5G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  421537792 488390655  66852864  31.9G Linux swap

GPT PMBR size mismatch (488390919 != 488397167) will be corrected by w(rite).
Disk /dev/sdb: 232.9 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 079A0748-C6FE-4AF3-AA2B-0C7B0DAE147D

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1       2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sdb2    1050624 421537791 420487168 200.5G Linux filesystem
/dev/sdb3  421537792 488390655  66852864  31.9G Linux swap

Disk /dev/mapper/isw_cehacfhcg_GNU_RAID1_PAIR: 232.9 GiB, 250056151040 bytes, 488390920 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 079A0748-C6FE-4AF3-AA2B-0C7B0DAE147D

Device                                             Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/mapper/isw_cehacfhcg_GNU_RAID1_PAIR-part1      2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/mapper/isw_cehacfhcg_GNU_RAID1_PAIR-part2   1050624 421537791 420487168 200.5G Linux filesystem
/dev/mapper/isw_cehacfhcg_GNU_RAID1_PAIR-part3 421537792 488390655  66852864  31.9G Linux swap

GPT PMBR size mismatch (1565561095 != 5860533167) will be corrected by w(rite).
Disk /dev/sdc: 2.7 TiB, 3000592982016 bytes, 5860533168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 079FB41D-0D42-47BB-8258-58814EC2CD68

Device     Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdc1   2048 1565560831 1565558784 746.5G Linux filesystem

GPT PMBR size mismatch (1565561095 != 5860533167) will be corrected by w(rite).
Disk /dev/sdd: 2.7 TiB, 3000592982016 bytes, 5860533168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 079FB41D-0D42-47BB-8258-58814EC2CD68

Device     Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdd1   2048 1565560831 1565558784 746.5G Linux filesystem

Disk /dev/mapper/isw_eabehgedbj_HOME_RAID1_PAIR: 746.5 GiB, 801567281152 bytes, 1565561096 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 079FB41D-0D42-47BB-8258-58814EC2CD68

Device                                           Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/mapper/isw_eabehgedbj_HOME_RAID1_PAIR-part1  2048 1565560831 1565558784 746.5G Linux filesystem

GPT PMBR size mismatch (732566015 != 732566645) will be corrected by w(rite).
Disk /dev/sde: 2.7 TiB, 3000592982016 bytes, 732566646 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: E9A6EC18-0588-4AA1-8BB0-02BA9A99CC2B

Device     Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sde1    256 732565759 732565504  2.7T Microsoft basic data

Disk /dev/mapper/luks-c57a597b-4396-4f1a-aac6-faee4902f6d6: 2.7 TiB, 3000587251712 bytes, 732565247 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Comment: I'm stretching the limits of my knowledge here... but let me ask the question... your 2.7TB drives are probably Western Digital "advanced format" drives, yes? When you initialize them, is there an option/qualifier to specify sector size? These WD drives use 4096 byte sectors... which requires some special handling. Can you check the WD web site for Linux drivers for these drives? Let me know if I'm on the right track. Cheers, Al

Comment: ps: you might check this <https://community.wd.com/t/problem-with-wd-advanced-format-drive-in-linux-wd15ears/13112> Cheers, Al

Comment: ps#2: and this one on partition alignment <https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-linux-on-4kb-sector-disks/> Cheers, Al

Comment: ps#3: and this... <http://askubuntu.com/questions/337693/how-to-format-a-4k-sector-hard-drive> Cheers, Al

Comment: ps#4: mkfs.ext4 -b 4096 /dev/sdc1 Cheers, Al

Comment: Thanks heynnema. I am not using a WD, but dual Seagate ST3000DM001's.

Comment: Same thing still applies. The 4K sectors may be tripping you up. Did you read the url's that I posted? They discuss these problems. Partition alignment. Sector size. etc. Cheers, Al

Comment: See <http://www.seagate.com/tech-insights/advanced-format-4k-sector-hard-drives-master-ti/> for more background info. Cheers, Al

Comment: But is there any way to fix the sector size without unmounting the partition? It contains my home directory. Further, /dev/sdc1 is just half of the RAID1 array. The other half is /dev/sdd1. So I don't think I could make a change to only one of them at a time, unless you meant mkfs.ext4 -b 4096 /dev/mapper/isw_eabehgedbj_HOME_RAID1_PAIR-part1 ?

Comment: You can't fix/change the sector size. You can't make changes to the partition alignment without backing up your /home first. Partitions should be aligned on 4K boundries. Changes you make to sdc1 also need to be made to sdd1. I just gave the mkfs.ext4 command as one example dealing with 4K sector sizes. The depth of my knowledge runs out here on this topic. I think that I gave you enough information to point you in a possible direction, and to research it further on your own. I would be interested in hearing the final outcome. Cheers, Al